# Firebase Web and AngularFire with Stripe API

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, angularfire

I am building a web app with Firebase and AngularFire. I need to implement a payment system like Stripe, but after a lot of documentations, It seems that it needs a server. Is-there anyone who knows a solution to manage with it ? Don't answer Zapier, it's not working well.

I will be very interested and grateful to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating directly with Stripe does require a backend server. If you're looking to accept payments with only client-side code (i.e. HTML + JavaScript), you can take a look at [third-party integrations](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations) such as [Commence Payments](https://www.commencepayments.com/), or payment forms you can redirect your users to like [Plasso.co](https://plasso.co/).

Comment: I see what you mean ! but i've build a script on [Webscript](https://www.webscript.io) which acts like a backend server. Now i would like to update my firebase dataBase when a user is charged. If you have an idea how can i manage it ? I can't create a method that update my data when the checkout form is send, i've tried to access to click which a Jquery $( "#formSubmit" ).click() but didn't succeed..